# Можно ли упростить следующий JavaScript код:

Tags: javascript, best-practice

Я в цикле добавляю элементы в массив.

Вот упрощенный код:

```
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if(!arr['foo']) {
      arr['foo'] = [];
    }

    arr['foo'].push('bar');
  }
```

Можно ли как то избежать проверки, перед присваиванием элементов в массив?

В php это делается так:

```
$arr['foo'][] = 'bar';
```

Comment: `Можно ли как то избежать проверки, перед присваиванием элементов в массив? Как например это делается в php.` - разве там не проверяется?

Comment: Ну я имею ввиду, что там не нужно писать код проверки.

Comment: разве? можешь аналогичный и полный пример написать показать на php, но без проверки?

Comment: собственно строка с php кодом и является примером. Если её запустить и вывести $arr, все будет корректно.

Comment: можно использовать объект. т.к. он, в какой-то степени, является ассоциативным массивом. `var obj = {
    'row1' : {
        'key1' : 'input1',
        'key2' : 'inpu2'
    },
    'row2' : {
        'key3' : 'input3',
        'key4' : 'input4'
    }
};` ..... а обращаться можно также через квадратные скобки `obj['row1']['key1']` .......... микс объекта и массива `var mixed = {
    'row1' : ['input1', 'inpu2'],
    'row2' : ['input3', 'input4']
};`

Answer (score 0):

Можно заранее инициализировать нужные объекты:

```js
arr = {}
arr['foo'] = []

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    arr['foo'].push('bar');
}

console.log(arr)
```

Или:

```js
items = []

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    items.push('bar');
}

arr = {}
arr['foo'] = items

// Или:
// arr = {
//     foo: items
// }

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Без проверки нельзя, потому что метод `push()` он же собственно у массива вызывается.

**Более короче можно сделать так**

```js
var arr = {};

(arr.foo = arr.foo || []).push('bar');
(arr.foo = arr.foo || []).push('bar');
(arr.foo = arr.foo || []).push('bar');

(arr[1] = arr[1] || []).push('bar');
(arr[1] = arr[1] || []).push('bar');
(arr[1] = arr[1] || []).push('bar');

console.log(arr);
```

**Или так**

```js
var arr = {};

(arr.foo || (arr.foo = [])).push('bar');
(arr.foo || (arr.foo = [])).push('bar');
(arr.foo || (arr.foo = [])).push('bar');

(arr[1] || (arr[1] = [])).push('bar');
(arr[1] || (arr[1] = [])).push('bar');
(arr[1] || (arr[1] = [])).push('bar');

console.log(arr);
```